# Res.render method - express and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Newbie questions. Am I right that res.render() is for serverside rendering and res.send() is for client side rendering? Or I just dont understand this two concepts (I mean server side rendering and client side rendering)? If not, it is even possible to do boty things using express and ejs?

Comment: everything in `express` is server side..  The returned HTML / CSS / JS etc.  it creates though will be clientSide.

Answer (score 1):

`res.render` does serverside rendering (it fills a template with content). What you do with `res.send` is up to you. But actually every content you send is rendered (displayed) on the client side, thats what the web is all about.

Comment: Adding my two cents: `res.render` renders "a view and send the rendered HTML string to the client" https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render 
and `res.send`sends the HTTP response https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send